# How to create and event handler inside a Singleton class - Javascript

Tags: javascript, singleton, custom-events

I have the next code:

```
// Singleton
var mySingleton = (function () {
    // Private methods and variables

    function privateMethod(){
        console.log( "I am private" );
    }

    var privateVariable = "Im also private";

   return {
      // Public methods and variables
      hello: function () {
        console.log( "I want to ''fire'' the event 'hello'" );
      }
    };
})();
```

And I want to create my own event handling system. I'm tried with the following code:

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

    function privateMethod(){
        console.log( "I am private" );
    }

    var handlers = {};
    mySingleton.prototype.registerHandler = function(event, callback) {
       this.handlers[event] = callback;
    };
    mySingleton.prototype.fire = function(event) {
       this.handlers[event]();
    };

    var privateVariable = "Im also private";

    return {
      hello: function () {
        console.log( "I want to ''fire'' the event 'hello'" );
        fire('hello');
      }
    };

})();
```

And I used as follows:

```
mySingleton .registerHandler('hello', function () {
    alert('Hi!');
});
```

But this doesn't work... Throw me the next error:

```
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Anybody can help me, please?

**MY CURRENT ERROR:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mycustomevent' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mycustomevent' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to make assignments to the "prototype" property of an object that doesn't exist yet. There's really no point anyway; just put those methods in the object you're returning:

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

    function privateMethod(){
        console.log( "I am private" );
    }

    var handlers = {};
    var privateVariable = "Im also private";

    return {
      hello: function () {
        console.log( "I want to ''fire'' the event 'hello'" );
        this.fire('hello');
      },
      registerHandler: function(event, callback) {
        handlers[event] = callback;
      },
      fire: function(event) {
        if(handlers[event]){
           handlers[event]();
        }else{
           console.error("Sorry, there aren't any handlers registered with that name");
        }
      }
    };
})();
```

The object you're building as "mySingleton" is just a plain object; that is, it's an instance of the Object constructor. There's no new prototype involved.

You don't need a `this` reference to access the "handlers" map because it's in the closure scope of the event handling functions. The way the code is arranged, however, *does* require `this` when using the `.fire()` API, though that could be fixed too by having the service functions be locally declared in the anonymous wrapper.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you correction. But... when I try to use it:
mySingleton .registerHandler('mycustomevent', function() {
            ...
});
And the mySingleton.fire('mycustomevent');

Throw me the next errors:

 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mycustomevent' of undefined
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mycustomevent' of undefined

May you can help me with this, please?

Comment: ¡Sorry! I forgot remove the "this" reference. It works fantastic. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @MartaFernandez ok, well I'm happy it's working for you!

Comment: Do you think I should to write code for check if the event in fire was be registered? If I use the method "hello" without call registerHandler before I have the next error: undefined is not a function (MySingleton.fire)

Comment: Yes, you could check and throw some sort of helpful exception. That's not too common in JavaScript libraries, but I don't see anything wrong with doing it. My favorite frameworks are generally those that provide helpful, explanatory errors when possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code**

```js
var singleton = (function(){
    var instance;
    var myObj = function(){
        this.name = "myObj";
        this.eventObj = {};
    };
    var localFn = function(){
        if(!instance){
            instance = new myObj();//singleton, instance created once
        }
        return instance;
    };
  //add 2 functions on myObj
    myObj.prototype.addEvent = function(evName, cb){
        this.eventObj[evName] = cb;
    };
    myObj.prototype.invokeEvent= function(evName){
        this.eventObj[evName]();
    };
    return localFn;
}());

singleton().addEvent("btnClick", function(){alert("click event invoked")});
singleton().addEvent("btnClick_1", function(){alert("click event invoked")});
singleton().invokeEvent("btnClick"); //alert "click event invoked"
```